# What the difference between dict_proxy in python2 and mappingproxy in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-internals

I notice when I create class in python2 it stores attributes in `dict_proxy` object:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
>>> A.__dict__
dict_proxy({....})
```

But in python3 `__dict__` returns `mappingproxy`:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
>>> A.__dict__
mappingproxy({....})
```

Is there any difference between two of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real difference, it [just got renamed](https://hg.python.org/cpython/diff/c3a0197256ee/Objects/descrobject.c).

When it was proposed to expose the type in the `typing` module in [issue #14386](http://bugs.python.org/issue14386), the object was renamed too:

> I'd like to bikeshed a little on the name. I think it should be
>   MappingProxy. (We don't use "view" much but the place where we do use
>   it, for keys/values/items views, is very different I think. Also
>   collections.abc already defines MappingView as the base class for
>   KeysView and friends.)

and

> Anyway, you are not the first one who remarks that we already use "view" to define something else, so I wrote a new patch to use the "mappingproxy" name (exposed as types.MappingProxyType).

The change [made it into Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#types), so in Python 3.2 you'll still see the old name.